# How to get lsn(xid) numbers of transactions from WAL file?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm looking for a way of getting transactions from `WAL` files.
Basically I need their `LSN` numbers.
(ideally both transactions `LSN` numbers and `WAL` files first and last `LSN` numbers)

I have a PostgreSQL cluster binary backup and set of `WAL` files.

I would like to perform `PITR` but first I need to find the point where I need to restore to.
So I need to find a particular transaction `LSN` or `XID` number which later I'm goin to use as `recovery_target`.

Could you please give an idea how to get `LSN` numbers or `XID` numbers from `WAL` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Run `pg_waldump` on the WAL segment.

Then you will get lines like

```
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):    115/   115, tx:        564, lsn: 0/01FECDB0, prev 0/01FECC88, desc: HOT_UPDATE off 1 xmax 564 flags 0x60 ; new off 2 xmax 0, blkref #0: rel 1663/16385/1417 blk 0
```

In there you have `tx: 564, lsn: 0/01FECDB0`, which is your desired information.